# On button click change images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to change 5 or more images, on button click. I created some code, but cannot understand why it doesn't work. You can find my code here(I want to change images on the 2 picture):

```
var images = [
    'img/tent1.png',
    'img/tent2.png',
    'img/tent3.png',
    'img/tent4.png',
    'img/tent5.png',
    'img/tent6.png'
],
    i=1;
for (var j = images.length; j--;) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = images[j];
}
$("#change").click('click', function (e) {
    $('#awnings').attr('src', images[i >= images.length - 1 ? i = 0 : ++i]);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Lzypuze/2/

Any thoughts? Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5vr419L6/1/

Comment: @Arun P Johny I've done the same thing in my project, but it doesn't work... How can it be possible? I need to change images on the 2 picture. http://jsfiddle.net/4Lzypuze/2/

Comment: Are you adding **JQuery Library** to your file?

Comment: of course. jquery-2.1.4.min.js